# Finding coordinates of a third point using vector algebra

Tags: vector-analysis

Sorry I didn't know how to make the title better to represent the question properly, but here it goes. You have 3 trees on an island. Let's call them **A**,**B** and **D**. You walk from **D** to **A**, then you turn 90∘ to the left and walk the same distance, and then mark that point, let's call it **K1**. Then, you walk from **D** to **B**, then you turn 90∘ to the right and walk the same distance and mark that point as **K2**. In the middle point between **K1** and **K2** is the treasure! However, when you go to the island, you see that **D** tree is gone! How can you find the treasure by using vector algebra? (using complex numbers is not allowed)

Comment: So when you show up, the only thing you see is Tree A and Tree B?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? The problem clearly suggests that the treasure point $\mathbf X$ is independent of $\mathbf D$, so if you work out the coordinates of $\mathbf K_1$, $\mathbf K_2$ and their midpoint, the coordinates of $\mathbf D$ should cancel.

Comment: Not sure how to explain what I tried without drawing but I tried connecting A and B, then from the imaginary treasure point, I draw perpendicular line to A-B line, and also draw a line that would be in the middle of said line. That makes A-B=2(x+y) meaning middle point is x+y distance away from both points, also x is distance between middle and perpendicular line. That's how far I got so far :/

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2312508/265466.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s do this first using the prohibited complex numbers, as the solution is a bit simpler when expressed that way. We can then translate it into vectors.

Multiplying $i$ rotates a complex number 90° counterclockwise, and multiplying by $-i$ rotates it clockwise. Using this we have $$K_1=A+(A-D)\,i \\ K_2=B-(B-D)\,i$$ and their midpoint is $$\begin{align}X=\frac12(K_1+K_2)&=\frac12[A+(A-D)\,i+B-(B-D)\,i] \\ &=\frac12(A+B)+\frac12(A-B)\,i.\end{align}$$ The location of the treasure is independent of $D$, so we can find the treasure without this tree, as suggested by the problem. The resulting equation for $X$ tells us where to dig: go halfway from $B$ to $A$, turn left, and go the same distance.

The above calculations translate directly into vector terms. Let $R$ represent a 90° counterclockwise rotation. Then we have $$K_1=A+R(A-D)=(I+R)A-RD \\ K_2=B+R^{-1}(B-D)=(I+R^{-1})B-R^{-1}D$$ and $$X=\frac12[(I+R)A-RD+(I+R^{-1})B-R^{-1}D].$$ Now, since these are 90° rotations, then for any vector $V$, $R^{-1}V=-RV$, so this equation becomes $$\begin{align}X &= \frac12[(I+R)A-RD+(I-R)B+RD] \\ &=\frac12[A+RA+B-RB] \\ &= \frac12(A+B)+\frac12R(A-B).\end{align}$$ Finally, $R(x,y)=(-y,x)$, so in terms of coordinates, $$X=\frac12(x_A+x_B,y_A+y_B)+\frac12(y_B-y_A,x_A-x_B).$$