# Find a treasure using complex numbers

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

(If you can think of a better title, feel free to edit)

> An old scroll describes the place where a group of pirates buried a
>   treasure:
>
> ```
> > In the island there are only 2 trees, A and B, and the remnants of a
> > hanging place.
> > 
> > Start at the hanging place and count the steps to go in a straight
> > line to tree A. When you arrive, turn 90º to the left and walk the
> > same amount of steps. Where you stopped, place a mark on the ground.
> > 
> > Go back to the hanging place and count the steps to tree B, also in a
> > straight line.  When there, turn 90º to the right and walk the same
> > amount of steps forward and place a mark on the ground.
> > 
> > Dig in the spot that's halfway through both marks and you'll find the
> > treasure.
> ```
>
> A young adventurer found the scroll. He travelled to the island and
>   could easily find the trees, but the hanging place was long gone
>   without a trace.
>
> Show that the location of the treasure does not depend on the position
>   of the hanging place, but only of the two trees.
>
> Hints:
>
> - Start by drawing the map.
>
> [image]
>
> - Consider the complex numbers that represent the positions of the trees, hanging place and treasure and translate the steps of the
>     geometrical construction into operations with complex numbers.

(F = hanging place)

I messed with the picture a bit:

[image]

With a and b complex numbers, I get $a = F-A$ and $b = F-B$. I can also see that [FA$M_1$] and [FB$M_2$] are isosceles triangles. If I try to find the hypotenuse of each, I get the locations of $M_1$ and $M_2$:

[image]

$$(h_1)^2 = a^2+a^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
(h_1)^2 = 2a^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
h_1 = \sqrt{2}a$$

$$h_2 = \sqrt{2}b$$

If T is the midpoint of $[M_1M_2]$ then the coordinates of T are $\frac{\sqrt{2}a+\sqrt{2}b}{2}=\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{(a+b)}{2}$.

$\frac{(a+b)}{2} = x+yi$, so $T = \sqrt{2}x+\sqrt{2}yi$.

I know that $|x+yi|= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|\sqrt{2}x+\sqrt{2}yi| = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

So basically, to find T all you need is to find the midpoint of A and B and multiply by a scalar of $\sqrt{2}$? But how do you multiply if you don't know the values of A and B? Or do you just use any random point as the origin?

Is this correct? I feel something is off.

Comment: The same problem as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276768/265466.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your work above, you say:

"If $T$ is the midpoint of $[M_1,M_2]$ then the coordinates of $T$ are $\frac{\sqrt{2}a+\sqrt{2}b}{2}=\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{(a+b)}{2}$

This is only true if $F$ lies on $M_1, M_2$  The distance from $M_1$ to $M_2$ only equals $h_1 + h_2$ if all of the segments $[F,M_1], [F,M_2]$ lie on the same line.

Using complex numbers as the title suggests:

Multiplying by a complex number by $i$ turns the vector 90 degrees to the left and does not change the length.

$M_1 = (A-F) + i(A-F) + F = A + i(A-F)\\
M_2 = B - i(B-F)\\
T = \frac 12 (M_1 + M_2)$

$T = \frac 12(A + iA + B - i B) = \frac 12(A+B) + \frac 12 (A-B)i$

At this point you are done, as you have shown that the location of T does not depend of F.

However, it also means that $ABT$ form a $45-45-90$ right triangle.

Comment: So what did I do wrong, exactly?

Comment: You used classical geometry and not complex numbers?  As you have it $a,b$ are one dimensional scalars, and you have then said that the coordinates of T are a scalar.  So, somewhere you lost track of what you were actually trying to do, or what your variables represented.

Comment: How are a and b one dimensional scalars? And why is A = (A-F) and not (F-A)?

Comment: You say $h_1 = 2a^2$  implying $a$ is a scalar.  As for my notation: $(A-F)$ is the vector from $F$ to $A$  Head minus tail, is standard notation.

Comment: I said $h_1 = \sqrt{2}a$, where a is a complex number. Why do you add F to $M_1$?

Comment: $h_1 = (1+i) a \ne \sqrt 2 a$  you could say $|h_1| = \sqrt 2 |a|$ but that would mean something else.  Why did I add F....   You start at $F,$ you add $(A-F)$ to arrive at $A.$  And you add $i(A-F)$ to arrive at $M_1.$  I did the same thing to find $M_2.$ I just didn't show the intermediate step because it was identical to the one above.